# Fitting a plot with multi-line y labels

Tags: r, plot, par

I am implementing this analysis in R: download the dataset, creation of a zoo object and plot the dataset.

```
library(tseries)
library(zoo)

start <- "2011-01-01"
end <- "2014-12-31"

MET <- get.hist.quote("MET", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MHK <- get.hist.quote("MHK", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MJN <- get.hist.quote("MJN", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MKC <- get.hist.quote("MKC", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MLM <- get.hist.quote("MLM", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MMC <- get.hist.quote("MMC", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MMM <- get.hist.quote("MMM", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MNK <- get.hist.quote("MNK", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MNST <- get.hist.quote("MNST", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)
MO <- get.hist.quote("MO", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)  
MON <- get.hist.quote("MON", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)  
MOS <- get.hist.quote("MOS", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)  
MPC <- get.hist.quote("MPC", quote="Close", start=start, end=end) 
MRK <- get.hist.quote("MRK", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)  
MRO <- get.hist.quote("MRO", quote="Close", start=start, end=end)

Series <- zoo(cbind(MET, MHK, MJN, MKC, MLM, MMC, MMM, MNK, MNST, MO,
                    MON, MOS, MPC, MRK, MRO))
colnames(Series) <- c("MetLife", "Mohawk", "\nMead\nJohnson",
                      "McCormick", "Martin\nMarietta", 
                      "Marsh and\nMcLennan", "3M", "Mallinckrodt",  
                      "Monster\nBeverage", "Altria", "Monsanto", 
                      "The Mosaic\nCompany", "Marathon\nPetroleum",  
                      "Merck", "Marathon Oil")
Series <- na.approx(Series)

plot(Series, main = "", xlab = "")
```

In order to present a better-looking graph, I have introduced the command `\n` to split the y label names in 2 lines. But the graphical output puts the the left y labels out of the margin.

[image: R Plot Example]

I have tried to modify both mar and mai in the function `par()` without any change at all of my output. I think this maybe can be linked to object drawn (a zoo object).

Answer (score 0):

[tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org) - especially `ggplot` makes it a bit easier to get reasonably looking graphics without tuning three-letter-acronymed parameters ad infinitum:

```
library(tidyverse)

Series %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(date = row.names(.) %>% as.Date) %>%
  gather(ticker, price, -date) %>%
  filter (!is.na(price)) ->
  dl

dl %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, price)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~ticker, strip.position = "left", ncol = 2)
```

[image: tickers in ggplot]

NB: You can even get the `\n` wrapping automatically with `facet_wrap(..., labeller = labeller(ticker = label_wrap_gen(10))`

NB2: some of the series did not download (all NAs), I did not bother

Comment: I was thinking too to ggplot2. But i prefer the output given by the normal plot. Using the ggplot all the series smooth in order to have the same Y scale. Could you please help me modify the margin of the above image?

Comment: Sounds like you need `facet_wrap(.., scales = "free_y")` ;). Sorry, I don't do/know base graphics in R at all, but I suspect `zoo` will have it's own `plot` method, which can happily ignore the `par()` settings..

Comment: After a little googling I found [this](https://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_time_series/history.html), where `autoplot.zoo()` would probably make it even easier to plot your data.